# Summation with Legendre Symbol $\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\big(\frac{a}{p}\big)a=0$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am trying to show the following: if $p$ is prime that is $1$ modulo 4, then $$\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\bigg(\frac{a}{p}\bigg)a=0$$
I know I need to use the fact that for an odd prime p, $\frac{p−1}{2}$ of the numbers $1\leq k \leq p−1$ are quadratic residues, but I do not know how $p$ being $1$ modulo $4$ comes into play. Do I need to use Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares which tells me that $p$ is the sum of two squares? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is the set of quadradic residues, then this sum is equal to $$-\sum_{a = 1}^{p-1} a + 2\sum_{a \in S} a = 2\sum_{a \in S} a - \frac{p(p-1)}{2}.$$

Since $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$, $-1$ is a quadradic residue, so each quadradic residue appears in a pair $a$ and $ p -a$.  There are $\frac{p-1}{4}$ total pairs and each pair sums to $p$, so this gives $$2\cdot p\frac{(p-1)}{4} - \frac{p(p-1)}{2} = 0.$$

Comment: $(\frac{-1}{p})= (-1)^{(p-1)/2}=1$

Comment: @Marcus M,  Hello, thanks for your answer. Can you explain why $-1$ is a quadratic residue when $p$ is 1 mod 4? Also that this implies each quadratic residue appears in a pair?

Comment: Yeah, as @reuns commented: we have $(\frac{-1}{p}) = (-1)^{(p-1)/2} = 1$.  This means $-1$ is a quadratic residue.  Now, if $a$ and $b$ are quadratic residues, then so is $ab$.  So for each quadratic residue $a$, $(-1)(a) \equiv p-a$ is a quadratic residue.

Comment: How do you know the original sum is equal to the one you have?